# Get values from another workbook based on cell values matching sheet names vba

Tags: vba, excel

The code I have works fine but I can't figure out how to get the code to step through an Array of cell values to match an Array of sheet names, then if the value and sheet name matches then get the offset cell value from that sheet.
If no value found go to the next value/Sheet. Can someone help with this please?.

```
Sub Data()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, mywb As String, LR As Long, c As Range, x As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
mywb = "Part Description 2017.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Part Description 2017.xlsx"
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Part Description 2017.xlsx")
Set sh1 = wb1.ActiveSheet
Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets("Customer Prefix")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
For Each c In Range("B2:B" & LR)
    Set x = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not x Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = x.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
Next
Set x = Nothing
Workbooks(mywb).Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Your existing code is looping through a range of cells - what is that you want to add? Is it a list of sheet names, and if so, does this exist somewhere?

Comment: You might want to look at the INDIRECT function

Comment: I am trying to get the cell value for the active sheet using another workbook sheet, I have 50+ sheets of data in that workbook and 10+ specific words I need values for in the active sheet but can have up to 7000 rows. I would like to step through and match the specific words in the active sheet against the sheet name from the other workbook. If found then add the cell value from the matched sheet to the active sheet. If not found then go to next word,

Comment: Also is it possible to add the values to a column where a specific header name is instead of the range being set to just one column.